# jQuery appended HTML doesn't nest correctly in Chrome

Tags: jquery, html, append

I've got the following string of HTML built up in JavaScript:

```
var s = "<p id='main'><p>Sample paragraph text.</p><p>more</p></p>";
```

Which, formatted, looks like this:

```
<p id='main'>
   <p>Sample paragraph text.</p>
   <p>more</p>
</p>
```

However, when I use jQuery's `append` method to add this to a `div`, it is added like this:

```
<p id='main'></p>
<p>Sample paragraph text.</p>
<p>more</p>
```

You can replicate [**for yourself in JsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/JnK96/), it happens for me at least in Chrome:

[image]

After you run it, right click on the paragraph and choose "Inspect Element".

This causes a problem for me because **I'm expecting to be able to select the parent paragraph by it's ID, and get the inner HTML** using `.html()`, but obviously this results in an empty string.

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Comment: I don't think nested paragraph tags are valid.

Comment: ^^^ It's because the browser is trying to fix your mistakes

Comment: wow really? dumb question then! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't nest paragraphs. Use a div to wrap the paragraphs instead.

Comment: I feel like I should have known this, oh well. Thank you for the crazy fast answer!

Answer (score 1):

as everybody else says,nesting of paragraphs is not valid while appending as html. You can wrap that html in `span` or `div`.later on, unwrap the parent used.something like this:

```
var s = "<span><p id='main'><p>Sample paragraph text.</p><p>more</p></p></span>";
$("#container").append(s);
$("#container span p").unwrap();
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JnK96/1/)**